# What should I do for this?

Tags: python

> Problem  : program should read two positive integers n and m, where n
>   and m are the numbers of rows and columns, respectively (0 < n, m <
>   100). For example, the following table is the result when n = 2
>   and m = 3.

This is my code. But it’s wrong. 
Please help me.

```py
def line():
    print('+---+')

def repeat(c, n):
    print(c * n)

def box(row, col): 
    while row > 0:
        repeat(line, n)
        print('|   |')
        row = row - 1
    print('+---+'*n)

    while col > 0:
        repeat(line, m)
        print('|   |')
        col = col - 1
    print('+---+'*m)


n = int(input())
m = int(input())
box(n, m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the function line like this, do instead `line()`. Also if you use two while loop it will print a 2x2 grid and a 3x3 one.
Below is another way to do it with a recursive function.

```
def repeat(row, col):
    if row == 0:
        return
    print(col * '+---' + '+')
    print(col * '|   ' + '|')
    return repeat(row-1, col)

def box(row, col): 
    repeat(row, col)
    print(col * '+---' + '+')

n = int(input("rows: "))
m = int(input("cols: "))
box(n, m)


Output:
rows: 2                                                                                                                                                                     
cols: 3                                                                                                                                                                     
+---+---+---+                                                                                                                                                               
|   |   |   |                                                                                                                                                               
+---+---+---+                                                                                                                                                               
|   |   |   |                                                                                                                                                                 
+---+---+---+
```